# Tableview change constraints to full screen when switch to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, constraints

Basically, I have a tableview and when I switch to landscape I want it to set the table view to fullscreen and when I switch it back to portrait, it should revert to default constraints. It works if I remove the breakpoint.

However, when I switch it back from landscape to portrait, it does not return to default. When I switch it back to portrait, I am editing the constraints for it to do what I want. However, I am open to other solutions. Please advise me on what I should do. I added the breakpoint using `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` just like this image:

[image: breakpoint log]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   parseData(noOfPosts:90)

   TableView.delegate = self
   TableView.dataSource = self
   TableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

   let myTop2Constraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
   let myBtm2Constraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50)

   myTop2Constraint.isActive = true
   myBtm2Constraint.isActive = true

   if(UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape){
      myTop2Constraint.isActive = false
      myBtm2Constraint.isActive = false
   }
}

override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   let myTop2Constraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
   let myBtm2Constraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50)
   let myTopConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0)
   let myBtmConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = TableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)

   myTopConstraint.isActive = false
   myBtmConstraint.isActive = false
   myTop2Constraint.isActive = false
   myBtm2Constraint.isActive = false

   if(UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape){
      self.catIsuSemasa.isHidden = true
      self.catOthers.isHidden = true
      self.catSocial.isHidden = true
      self.catPolitics.isHidden = true
      if(myTop2Constraint.isActive){
         print("error1?")
         myTop2Constraint.isActive = false
         print("error2?")
         myBtm2Constraint.isActive = false
         print("error3?")
         myTopConstraint.isActive = true
         myBtmConstraint.isActive = true
      }else{
         TableView.removeAllConstraints()
         myTopConstraint.isActive = true
         myBtmConstraint.isActive = true
      }
   }else{
      self.catIsuSemasa.isHidden = false
      self.catOthers.isHidden = false
      self.catSocial.isHidden = false
      self.catPolitics.isHidden = false
      if(myTopConstraint.isActive){
         print("error")
         myTopConstraint.isActive = false
         print("error2")
         myBtmConstraint.isActive = false
         print("error3")
         myTop2Constraint.isActive = true
         print("error4")
         myBtm2Constraint.isActive = true
         print("run?")
      }
   }
}

extension UIView {
    func removeAllConstraints() {
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeAllConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are set constrain programmatically you can do this same by storyboard using size class (vary for traits)?.
[this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/492-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started) might be help you to set different constrain for landscape and portrait in storyboard.

Comment: I am looking into it now, thanks for the pointer

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya hey, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I manage to use the vary for traits solution to fix my problem. If you post it it the answer's comment, ill make it a solution

Comment: Most Welcome , I added as answer so it will help full to other user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App support landscape and portrait  then we do not required set constrain programatically we can achieve same thing by using storyboard's size class (vary for traits). By using size class we can create adaptive layout design. we can set different constrain for landscape and portrait app.

Please check below tutorial link :

[Tutorial Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/492-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)